# PHP Forum Not Writing Data to Database

Tags: php, forum

The code that I am showing seems to stop working at $tid=mss 
This is why I think my function called mss at the beginning is not working.
When the script is ran on my website, it acts like nothing ever happened and goes back to the topic you were viewing.  Sorry for the short explanation, I don't know what is going on so there is nothing i can say.  Please comment on this if you need any questions.
Reply.php

```
  <?php
    require('connect.php');
    function mss($value) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($connect, $value)));
    }
if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "Invalid usage of the file!  Hmm, maybe you should try sql injection.";
} else {
    $tid = mss ($_GET['id']);
    $msg = mss ($_POST['reply']);

    if(!$tid) {
        echo "Hmm, I dont know how that you would reply to no topic but still expect it to work.";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE id='".$tid."'";
        $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0) {
            echo "Wat r u doin m7, you tryin to rply to a topic that doesn't exist.";
        } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            if(!$msg) {
                echo "You did not give a reply.";
            } else {
                if(strlen($msg) < 5 || strlen($msg) > 10000) {
                    echo "<font color='red'>Your reply must be between 5 and 10000 characters!</font>";
                } else {
                    $date = date("m-d-y") . " at " . date("h:i:s");
                    $time = time();
                    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO forum_replies (id, tid, uid, message, date, time) VALUES (default, '".$tid."','".$_SESSION['uid']."', '".$msg."', '".$date."', '".$time."')";
                    $res3 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql3) or die (mysqli_error());
                    header("Location: topics.php?id='.$tid'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

EDITS:  Updated Code

Connect.php

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";//hostname
    $username="********";//username
    $password="********";//database password
    $db_name="forum";//database name

    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name) or die ("<font color='red'>Unable to connect to MySQL!  Contact an admin.</font>");
?>
```

Comment: check few things first is your connection with database has been done properly, if it has been done the issue not with your mss funtion, mysqli_real_escape_string fire error only when database is connect properly, else put debug on each line so that you will come to know from where the had stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

The function `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires a mysqli connection to be passed as the first parameter. Example usage would be `mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link, $value)` that `$db_link` variable is probably set in your connect.php file and is set by a call to `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working even though I added it at the beginning and added a $connect.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a connection? Could you provide the code form connect.php? (get rid of the real connection credentials before posting)

Comment: I am sure that I have a connection, otherwise, I wouldn't be able to post the topic I am trying to reply to.

Comment: I added the connect.php.